# Notify when network lost

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

How can i tell when the network status has changed on a device?

What permissions would i need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make an BroadcastReceiver that will be triggered when the connectivity status has changed

```
   public class InternetConnectionChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
   {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
                String reason = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
                boolean isFailover = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER, false);

                NetworkInfo currentNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
                NetworkInfo otherNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_OTHER_NETWORK_INFO);

                if(currentNetworkInfo.isConnected()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
```

add below permission in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Register your broadcast receiver in manifest file.

```
<receiver android:name="InternetConnectionChangeReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Thank u for your quick response ill try this,.